# Proof that every linear map from one normed vector sapce to the other (both finite-dimensional) is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The claim is that

> Given two finite-dimensional normed vector spaces $({\Bbb R}, V,‖⋅‖_V)$ and $({\Bbb R},W,‖⋅‖_W)$, every linear map $L:V→W$ is bounded w.r.t. $‖⋅‖_W$

I have a proof as the following,

> Choose a basis $v_1,…,v_n$ for $V$, then for a vector $u∈V$ with coordinate $x=(x_1,…,x_n)$, we have
>
> $‖L(u)‖_W=‖L(∑_{i=1}^nx_i v_i )‖_W=‖∑_{i=1}^nx_i L(v_i)‖_W≤∑_{i=1}^n|x_i | ‖L(v_i )‖_W ≤(\max_{i=1,…,n})‖L(v_i )‖_W  ‖x‖_1 ≤ \frac{\max_{i=1,…,n}‖L(v_i )‖_W}{m} ‖u‖_V$

The last inequality is due to a previous lemma. My question is I am not able to understand why this shows $L$ is bounded. No matter $‖x‖_1$ or $‖u‖_V$, they are dependent on $u$, and in general $‖x‖_1$ or $‖u‖_V$ are not bounded, then how do we say $‖L(u)‖_W$ is bounded (e.g. $e^x-1 < e^x$ for every $x$, but $e^x-1$ is not bounded)?

Comment: You should specify in the first line "two **finite-dimensional** vector space"

Comment: I think this is in general wrong and only holds for finite vector spaces. Consider for example the vector space $\mathbb R ^\mathbb{N}_0$ of finite sequences (or polynomials, whatever you prefer) with any norm. Then you can have the linear map to $\mathbb R$ which sents $(a_1, \dots ) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot a_i$.

Comment: @guestDiego Only $V$ needs to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: For linear maps between normed vector spaces, the term "bounded" doesn't mean what the term means when you're talking about functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$. It means there is a constant $C$ such that $\lVert Lu\rVert_W \leqslant C\cdot \lVert u\rVert_V$ for all $u \in V$. A reason for that terminology is that such maps map bounded subsets of $V$ to bounded subsets of $W$.

Answer (score 2):

You have shown
$$
‖L(u)‖_W≤ \frac{\max_{i=1,…,n}‖L(v_i )‖_W}{m} ‖u‖_V
$$
i.e. $‖L(u)‖_W≤ C ‖u‖_V$ where $C$ does not depend on $u$. Keep in mind that this is the very *definition* of bounded linear map. This means **not**,  for example in the case $W=\mathbb R$, that $L$ is a bounded function in the usual sense. In fact, in that sense there would be only one bounded linear function: the null function.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
K = \frac{\max_{i=1,…,n}‖L(v_i )‖_W}{m}
$$
It is a constant, that is, does not depend on $u$.  Then from
$$
\|L(u)\|_W \le K \|u\|_V
$$
we conclude that the linear map $L$ is "bounded".  See the definition of "bounded" for linear maps in the textbook you are using.